# Pyspark concat column to an array and explode values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to transpose column to rows .
First to concat columns into an array
Second step is to explode the array column

Explode function is not working ..

```
>>> filteredPaths1.select(   array ( concat( col("v1.id"),lit(","),col("v2.id"),lit(",") ,col("v2.id") )).alias("test")     ).printSchema()
root
 |-- test: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Values in array column -

```
>>> filteredPaths1.select(   array ( concat( col("v1.id"),lit(","),col("v2.id"),lit(",") ,col("v2.id") )).alias("test")     ).show(10,False)
+--------------------------------------------------------------+                ]
|test                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|[Sorter_SAMPLE_CUSTOMER,Join_Source_Target,Join_Source_Target]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However when trying to explode the array column it's not creating new rows , just giving the same output -

```
>>> filteredPaths1.select(   explode (array ( concat( col("v1.id"),lit(","),col("v2.id"),lit(",") ,col("v2.id") )).alias("test") )    ).show(10,False)
+------------------------------------------------------------+                  ]
|col                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|Sorter_SAMPLE_CUSTOMER,Join_Source_Target,Join_Source_Target|
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any reason explode is not working ?

Comment: [concat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat) creates a single string column out of your three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of you are using `array(concat(..))` means array of one value & exploding this you will get only one row, i.e same value.

Use `split` instead of `array`

```
filteredPaths1.select(explode(split(concat_ws(",",col("v1.id"),col("v2.id"),col("v2.id")),",")).alias("test"))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out , I have removed concat all together and it worked as well but thanks for providing solution .